# Android tablet freezes when running HLS stream at high quality

Tags: android, performance, http-live-streaming

I am running application on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1, which plays **HLS streams**, encrypted by **Verimatrix**. I am using 3rd party player integrated in my app. Streams switch quality among three profiles,

```
 <= 1MBps,
 <= 1.6MBps
 and 
 <=2.6MBps.
```

Playback is OK at low and medium, but at high, occasionally, tablet freezes completely and has to be rebooted manually. Anybody got similar experience? Is this sign of high demands of application on device? I am trying to find out root cause. Any hint appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is impossible to answer as the problem seems to be related to the 3rd media player. I suggest you ask the author(s) of that player.

Comment: If a device freezes so that you have to reboot it then something within the device is wrong. Small bugs within the device software are not uncommon especially related to video playback since that's extremely complex and is usually using hardware acceleration portions of the cpu.

Comment: player developers are puzzled too, so far, so no help from there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got this problem on my Galaxy Tab 7 too. I read on some sites that the problem is on HLS android implementation.

The following links talks about  Android's HLS problems.

The Pain of Live Streaming on Android 
http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/the-pain-of-live-streaming-on-android/

The Definitive Guide to HLS
http://features.encoding.com/http-live-streaming-hls/

Comment: uf ... that sounds really bad ... could you point me to some site where more information can be found? Thank you

Comment: So, this link explains a little about HLS and talks about its implementation problems. http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/the-pain-of-live-streaming-on-android/ or
http://features.encoding.com/http-live-streaming-hls/